# css-border radius

Tags: css, visual-studio

I am trying to use the following two properties in my styles.css:

```
border-radius: 8px; /*w3c border radius*/
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* w3c box shadow */
```

It comes up with the following message.

> They are not known css properties.

Comment: Where is this message? What browser are you using?

Comment: border -radius is not known css property name, box -shadow is not known css property name

Comment: Where is this error showing? In your editor? If so it can probably be ignored as it may not be css3 compliant yet. Also remember to use the `-moz` and `-webkit` equivalents too to cover the other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's a Visual Studio error message, right? If so, just ignore it. But do add browser specific versions of those rules to your css for older browsers. e.g. `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` etc.

Comment: Is there anything one can add to the CSS file so that Visual Studio 2010 knows to follow CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

If you have those errors in your browser you need to use the more border-radius types because all the browsers have there own.

an example for border-radius:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Safari and webkit  */    
border-radius: 5px; /* Opera, Chrome */ 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Mozilla (FF, Seamonkey) */
```

an example for box shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

Comment: HTML5 doctype has nothing to do with CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 1):

You get that message beacause these are css3 properties.
To check it's validity use:

```
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=EXAMPLE.COM/STYLE.CSS&profile=css3
```

replace EXAMPLE.COM/STYLE.CSS with url to your css file.

Answer (score 1):

Support for these CSS3 properties is growing, but a lot of browsers don't have it yet.

The latest Opera has the capability, Safari, Chrome and Firefox too but they require custom properties.

The best approach is to duplicate each property, once with the prefix `-moz-` and once with the prefix `webkit-`. Always write the standards compliant rule last. Like this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px; /*w3c border radius*/
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* w3c box shadow */
```

You can check which browser supports what on [Standardista](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-border-properties).

Comment: A much better link to find browser compatibility: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border).